# how do i enable https for all pages in my website

Tags: .htaccess

How to enable http to https on page loading

Since all of the links on my pages are relative, when someone visits `http://domain.com` and clicks on Buy, they are taken to `https://domain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```